# Keeping content centered vertically with only CSS?

Tags: css

I have a content area that should behave in the following way:

- Content is centered vertically if there's no vertical overflow (currently achieved via `display:table/-cell`)
- No scrollbar is displayed unless there is vertical overflow
- the height of the containing div never changes

I've only been able to satisfy the first point - **fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/125/

**Here's my html:**

```
<div class="row-fluid card-box">

    <div class="span4 side-study-box">
        <div class="side-box-content">
            <pre class="text-content-saved">TEST 
           TEST</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.side-study-box {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #3D6AA2;
    text-align: center;
    height: 160px;
    max-height: 160px;
    display: table ;
    margin: 0px ;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll ;
}

    .side-study-box .side-box-content {
        width: calc(100%);
        height: 160px;
        float: right;
        display: table;
        overflow-y: scroll ;
        background-color: white;
    }

    /*#region CONTENT AREAS */

    /*#region TEXT CONTENT */
    .side-study-box .text-content-saved {
        width: calc(100%+29px);
        font-size: 24px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        height: 160px !important;
        max-height: 160px ;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0px ;
        margin: 0px ;
        border: 0px ;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Unfortunately I can't use js as part of the solution... is this possible with only css?

Comment: What's with all the `!important`s? Are those really necessary? (`!important` is commonly seen as a last resort for when it's really, *really* necessary.)

Comment: @icktoofay that's me fighting with bootstrap.  I'll clean it up once I get things working.

Comment: IMO, It seems the question example needs a bit of improvement on cutting down unneeded code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use   `overflow:auto;` to achieve the second point and set the following:

word-break: normal !important;
word-wrap: normal !important;
white-space: pre !important;

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/134/

Keep in mind that since you are using a `pre` tag, it means that all the white spaces and line breaks formatting counts so any white space or extra line could cause the overflow and you might miss that. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirements - the scrollbar always shows, and the height changes if there's a lot of content

Comment: What do you want? You said the height never changes so I made it change with the content if they're bigger than 160px. The scrollbar does not show if the height is 160 or less.

Comment: it shouldn't ever change.  I listed the requirements, not the problems, hence "should behave in the following way:"

Comment: see my edit above. Hope it helps. I updated the fiddle. be careful what you put inside the pre as it could mislead you. It is working for me right now with all your requirement.

Comment: I do need to use pre tags because the linebreaks need to be counted - thank you for the heads up there.  The scrollbar in chrome seems to be a little quirky with any overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/139/  See how the scrollbar extends past 160px?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by quirky/extending past 160px? You probably want to add some padding-top and padding-bottom to your pre

Comment: If you use developer tools to inspect the height of the .pre.text-content-saved, you can see how that div's height is > 160px, making the scrollbar's bottom disappear

Comment: That's partly because of your relative positioning and nesting. for example if you set the .pre.text-content-saved's position:absolute. Then you will notice it.